# How to change PORT number and run serve forever?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, create-react-app, serve

I'm building an app with create-react-app and I'm serving the production version via serve. I would like to run it on port 80 and run it forever even after I log out of the terminal.

Comment: A dev server isn’t a suitable tool for serving a production application

Answer (score 1):

Look into learning a backend server framework like [Express](https://expressjs.com/) if you are interested in deploying your own production applications.

With Express, you can point specific URL requests to specific static files and apply any data retrieval / setting in the process.

There are also a number of specific [resources](https://dev.to/loujaybee/using-create-react-app-with-express) available for transitioning create-react-apps to Express backends.

When you make this jump, if you haven't already, the important thing to remember is that you are essentially coding two applications, one is the frontend application that user sees, which is rendered in their browser by the bundled React code, and the other application is the backend server which routes and organizes those static javascript files for delivery to the users browser. When they connect to your server, they are sent to Express, which in turn (depending on the request) sends the React javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Build application first,

```
sudo npm run build
```

Then,

```
sudo serve -s build -p 80
```